# How does session and cookie work in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I understand one of the strategies to store sessions is store it in the cookie. There is one thing I don't understand from the docs:

> To prevent session hash tampering, a digest is calculated from the
>   session with a server-side secret and inserted into the end of the
>   cookie.

What does this mean? How do they prevent that, if I get a cookie from another user, and I use it in my browser, I can't pretend I am the other user? I guess I don't understand what session hash tampering means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do they prevent that, if I get a cookie from another user, and I
>   use it in my browser, I can't pretend I am the other user?

This is called session hijacking, and is covered in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-hijacking. The recommended way to to mitigate this is by "always forcing SSL connection in your application config file", like so:

`config.force_ssl = true`

The whole http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html is definitely worth a read, for more goodness like this.

Comment: It's also worth noting that using a purely cookie based method for sessions does not allow users to manually invalidate a session (logout). That cookie will still be a valid session until it expires.

Comment: Thank you. I actually have read those guides, but I still have the doubt of the following. If I go into that person's computer, and I copy the cookie, and put it in my browser, I will be able to pretend that I am him, right? Or the ``digest`` will help with avoiding that? Specifically this part ``To prevent session hash tampering, a digest is calculated from the session with a server-side secret and inserted into the end of the cookie`` - What does this means?

Comment: This might help explain it - http://robertheaton.com/2013/07/22/how-to-hack-a-rails-app-using-its-secret-token/